# Do implicit intents do a broadcast internally?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

Following piece of code open an URL using implicit intent.

```
EditText editText  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url_editText);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(editText.getText().toString()));
                startActivity(myIntent);
```

It shows up all the applications that support this action Intent.ACTION_VIEW like Chrome, Firefox etc. Hence I am assuming this procedure internally does a broadcast with action  Intent.ACTION_VIEW. Please correct me if I have misunderstood.

As per above assumption I tried the foloowing code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

but it does not work. Nothing is shown. What is the difference. Can someone clear my confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with [IntentFilters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html). Before launching the `Activity`, it's asking the system to give it the list of everything that's an `Activity` and can handle the intent -- no broadcasting involved here.

As for `sendBroadcast()` -- it's essentially the same thing but for `BroadcastReceiver`s. The mechanism is the same: match intent filters, deliver the `Intent`, but the `Intent` is delivered to all the receivers regardless of their quantity (as opposed to what `startActivity()` does -- because it can only result in starting a single activity, hence the need to choose one if there are multiple that match).

I don't think there are any `BroadcastReceivers` registered for `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` (since it's an action whose purpose is to start an activity, there's no logical reason to listen for it and start nothing, except count activity launches or something) but you can register one yourself and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

> Hence I am assuming this procedure internally does a broadcast with action Intent.ACTION_VIEW.

No.

> but it does not work. Nothing is shown

Of course.

> What is the difference.

`startActivity()` != `sendBroadast()`. They are separate operations, just as addition and subtraction are separate mathematical operations.

If you wish to think of the `Intent` system as being a bit like a message bus, that bus has three *totally separate* channels:

- activities (`startActivity()`)
- services (`startService()`, `bindService()`)
- broadcasts (`sendBroadcast()`, `sendOrderedBroadcast()`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between those two is just who receives the `Intent`. If you call `sendBroadcast()` the `Intent` will be sent to `BroadcastReceivers`. If you call `startActivity()` the `Intent` will be sent to `Activities`. That's the reason why this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendBroadcast(myIntent);
```

Doesn't start an `Activity`, because the `Intent` is only visible to `BroadcastReceivers`.

The same goes for `startService()`. By calling that method the `Intent` will only target `Services`. I guess the confusion comes from the word broadcast. It implies that it is sent everywhere and visible to everyone, but that is not the case. Broadcasts are only visible to `BroadcastReceivers` just like if you call `startActivity()` the `Intent` will only target `Activities` and nothing else.

You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).